# How does PRINCE2 map to ITIL? Specifically Product Descriptions vs. Service Design Packages

Tags: prince2

What are the tangents or points of contact between PRINCE2 and ITIL?

E.g. can I say "A PRINCE2:Product Description IS A(N) ITIL:Service Design Package"? Or can I state that with some qualifications?

Or is it too complex to put in these terms?

I am looking for a couple of contact points, or a Web link to a white paper ;)

Background: I am PRINCE2 Practitioner certified and currently reading up to go for ITIL Foundation as well, but I am not yet familiar with the practicalities of ITIL at a design level.

Any kind of starting points here would be helpful as I need to write some of these descriptions of how a service should behave in an ITIL-controlled environment.

Comment: ITIL is about service delivery; PRINCE2 is for project management. They aren't directly related or interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, I was pretty clear on this point. I'm sold on the idea that they're not interchangeable, but is there really  no relationship at all?

Comment: I am not a prince II expert even though I work with it.  I am pembroke or PMP qualified.  ITIl is a framework - and best practices are taken from a variety of sources.  E.g. RACI analysis is used in PMP and also in ITIL.  They relate to both services and Project Managment and are used to identify roles of communication - Responsible, Accountible, Consulted and Informed.  I was confused starting out as well but there can be similarities.

Answer (score 1):

Prince two and ITIL are used in my organisation as well.  I have my foundation cert in ITIL from the BCS.  ITIL is a framework of best practices you can use and focuses on good service delivery.

On the other hand, Prince II is a method of project management.  We use Prince II for projects and the ITIL service desk software for managing the higher level stuff such as live incidents, error investigation, SQL requests, Change Orders, Infrastructure analysis, application downtime.

In a nutshell prince II is about the project, ITIL is about the service.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

IMO to answer your question in details we should make a serious cross-check analysis of almost every cell of the PRINCE2 vs. ITIL processes matrix.
(Sorry, it's a tremendous effort. The result would be too extensive to fit it in the Answer format.)

Generally, ITIL gives to the Project Manager detailed explanation how to implement a service to limit operational risks and inefficiencies after go-live. Furthermore, ITIL provides to the Project Manager clear set of stakeholders responsible for IT Services that should be involved in the project to express important part of non-functional requirements.

You can find a comprehensive framework that covers development as well as maintenance aspects in [COBIT 5](https://cobitonline.isaca.org/).